# airflow - use an operator inside a function

Tags: python, airflow

Im planning to use an airflow operator inside a function and then call it from a different task. For me, the task ran successfully, but it didn't trigger the operator inside the function.

```py
def func():
    t1 = BashOperator(
            task_id='print_date',
            bash_command='touch /tmp/aaaaaaaaaaaaa'
        )
    t1

main_dag = DAG(
    'bhuvitest',
    default_args=args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    catchup=False
)

bhuvitest = PythonOperator(
        task_id='python_task', 
        python_callable=func,
        dag = main_dag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work instead of `t1`:

```
t1.execute(dict())
```

The [airflow.operators documentation](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html#airflow.operators.BaseOperator.execute) can give more details.

Comment: Error: airflow 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Hi, tested it now and adapted my answer, needs to be `t1.execute(dict())`. None worked for some other operators.

Comment: hey, thanks it worked, May I know how adding `dict()` solved the issue? If I use any other operator can I still use this option?

Comment: Depends how these operators have implemented `execute`. I guess should work for most operators.